# How do I destructure an array wrapped in the Promise keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, psql, asynchronous-javascript

I am trying to retrieve data from a PSQL table. And this is my code for that:

```
async function requestData() {
   var selectQuery = `SELECT "fName", "lName", "phoneNumber", "eMail" FROM public."User"`;
   const {rows} = await client.query(selectQuery);
   client.end;
   return rows;
}
```

This function is returning:
[an array inside the Promise keyword. {[]}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdJLm.png)

I want to destructure the array inside to present the data and I cannot figure out any possible way of doing it. I tried using foreach loop and other ways but it is not working.

When this function runs in its own file, it gives normal output of an array of objects.

```
async function requestData() {
   var selectQuery = `SELECT "fName", "lName", "phoneNumber", "eMail" FROM public."User"`;
   const {rows} = await client.query(selectQuery);
   client.end;
   console.log(rows);
   return rows;
}
```

[It is giving normal output in the file, but when I am exporting this output, it is wrapping the output in the promise keyword. I tried going through the documentation but I didn't find any way to destructure this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdJLm.png)

This is the code in the file that I have imported:

```
const adminData = require("./data/adminDataObjects");
console.log(adminData.users.table);
```

And this is the code in the adminDataObjects file where I have defined this function:

```
users: {
    body: ``,
    table: requestData(),
    script: `<script>document.querySelector('.users').classList.add('active')</script>`,
  },
```

I am new to node js and I have already tried to search for the solution in different blog posts, stackoverflow answers and MDN documentation. I even read blog posts about asynchronous javascript and completed a tutorial on promises.

Comment: `async` functions always return promises.

Comment: How do I destructure it? @Andy

Comment: You either have to `await` your async function, or use the `then` method to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in one of the comment by Andy that the return type of an asynchronous function is a promise, it was the problem here.

I asked one of my friend to resolve the promise and the "Promise" keyword that was showing up went away. Apparently I was making a syntax error while resolving the promise.

This is the code with the problem that is returning return value as an array within an object of the promise keyword.

```
const adminData = require("./data/adminDataObjects");
console.log(adminData.users.table);
```

This is how I resolved this error:

```
    const adminData = require("./data/adminDataObjects");
    app.get("/admin/:path", async (req, res) => {
      const requestKeyword = req.params.path;
      if (requestKeyword === "dashboard") {
        res.render("admin-panel", { data: adminData.dashboard });
      } else if (requestKeyword === "users") {
        var finalValue
        await adminData.users.table.then((value)=>{
           finalValue=value;
        })
        console.log(finalValue);
      } else{
        res.render("admin-panel", { data: adminData.orders });
      }
    });
```

Comment: No, don't use `.then((value)=>{ finalValue=value; })`. Just write `const finalValue = await adminData.users.table;`